# How to stop afplay after a certain amount of time

Tags: ruby, core-audio

I made a battleship game in ruby. I have a method in my file that uses `afplay` at the end of the game. I am unable to stop the audio playback, it plays a song. I found the `-t` for `afplay` but can't find anywhere that says how to implement it. I have and am trying to throw it in there to see what works but still thought this would be a good resource. 
I would like to stop the song after about 20sec or so. `ctrl-c` doesn't work :(.  Thanks for any help.

`pid = fork{ exec 'afplay', "../filename.mp3" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it! `killall afplay`
For the timer I added `sleep 20` before the `killall afplay`

Comment: UGH THANK YOU. Was looking for this for C++. For those who are looking at this in the future:

To play the MP3, I used:
```
system("afplay intro_music.mp3 &>/dev/null &");
```
To stop:
```
system("killall afplay");
```

The MP3 file must be in the directory that you are compiling from. Thanks to the International Man of Coding Mystery lol